# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**when i run my flutter app i facing this problem:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBEz.png)

**What is this problem?**

Comment: clean your builds by  `flutter clean` and than try

Comment: i tried flutter clean, but still the same problem. @KartikPatel

Comment: I think its gradle versioning issue. Whats your gradle version and its plugin version? Check this versioning documentation might help you - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: its from run, the code is not the problem @TheAnonymousKoder

Comment: But we need the code if we want to post the **fixed** code @anasalhajhasan